# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'internal-db.xxxxx.gridserver.com' (4)

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I'm trying to connect to mySQL via Sequel Pro, but continue to receive the "MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'internal-db.xxxx.gridserver.com' (4)" error message.

mySQL is hosted via mediatemple.

I'm on macOS Sierra v 10.12.2

I've increased connection time to 30secs.

right before this error I couldn't connect with error code 61.  I've changed port from 3306 to 3307 which has bought me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Turns out I needed to refresh my allowed remote IP list with the host.